# How to make socket.io asynchronous method synchronous?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I was following the code snippet here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis#redisadapterclientsroomsarray-fnfunction

```
io.in('room3').clients((err, clients) => {
  console.log(clients); // an array containing socket ids in 'room3'
});
```

to get the clients in a particular room.

Is there a simple/idiomatic way I can make this snippet synchronous?  I want to loop over an array of rooms and synchronously get the count of users `clients.length` in each room (ie don't iterate over the loop until the user count of the current room has been retrieved.)

Comment: may be new Promise((resolve, reject), () => {
    io.in('room3').clients((err, clients) => {
        resolve(clients) // an array containing socket ids in 'room3'
      });
})

Comment: that doesn't mach the function synchronous. it just a promise that he can use async/await syntax over.

Comment: the answer is no, you can't force an asynchronous method to become synchronous bc of the particulars of the nodejs event loop. You can use async / await syntax and other libs to make it look like it is, but it still won't be truly. I'd switch the focus to the particular problem you're trying to solve and figuring out a pattern for solving this class of problem

Comment: more importantly, you really don't want it to be synchronous even if it were possible.  for example some of the answer examples put await in a loop to force request replies in sequence, when really it'd be better to have them just execute in parallel, because you don't care what order your requests come back in, only the total count.

Comment: the solution could realy be condensed to a simple one or two line Promise.all .map .reduce

Comment: @user120242 sometimes the order of async execution matters. I agree that parallel async execution is trivial, but OP specified sequential execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Promises` and `async await` within a `for` loop

```js
 async function getClients() {
    for(let room in rooms) {
      try{
       const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
           io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
              if(err) {
                 rej(err);
              } else {
                  res(clients); // an array containing socket ids in room
              }
           });
       })
       const clients = await promise;
       console.log(clients);
      }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
   };
}
```

Using the above manner will help you iterate over each room and get the clients sequentially one by one.

Although you can't force them to run synchronously

Answer (score 1):

### The other answers here seem to overcomplicate things. This can easily be done without any 3rd party libraries.

Wrapping a callback in a Promise gives you more control over the flow of the program.

```js
// The purpose of this is just to convert a callback to a Promise:
// clientsInRoom('room1') is a promise that resolves to `clients` for that room.
const clientsInRoom = room => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => 
    err ? reject(err) : resolve(clients)
  )
})
```

If you are inside of an async function, you can use await, which will make asynchronous code feel more like synchronous code. (although "top-level await" is supported within modules in modern browsers)

```js
async function main() {
  const rooms = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3']

  // If either one of the promises reject, the statement will reject
  // Alternatively, you can use Promise.allSettled()
  const allClients = await Promise.all(rooms.map(clientsInRoom))

  // You can use map to turn this into an array of the lengths:
  const lengths = allClients.map(clients => clients.length)

  // Alternatively, if you want the feel of a synchronous loop:
  for (const clients of allClients) {
    console.log(clients.length)
  }
}
```

Using for-await is also an option, if you want to start iterating before all promises have resolved:

```
async function main() {
  const rooms = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3']
  for await (const clients of rooms.map(clientsInRoom)) {
    console.log(clients.length)
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `resolve(clients)` be in the `else` statement? Otherwise both `reject` and `resolve` will be called on error. eg. `err ? reject(err) : resolve(clients)`

Comment: @3limin4t0r Calling resolve/reject in a promise multiple times will have no effect. Only the first call matters, which is why `else` is not needed here.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. Switched to using a ternary expression now to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you can't force asynchronous things to become synchronous in js. You can execute asynchronous things sequentially though (or in parallel if you wish).

callbacks:

```
function _getTotalClientsCb(rooms, count, cb) {
  if (rooms.length) {
    const room = rooms.shift()
    io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
      if (err) 
        return cb(err)
      count += clients.length;
      _getTotalClientsCb(rooms, count, cb)
    })
  } else {
    cb(null, count)
  }
}

function getTotalClientsCb(rooms, cb) {
  _getTotalClientsCb(rooms.slice(), 0, cb)
  // parallel execution
  // if (!rooms.length)
  //  cb(null, 0)
  // const allClients = [];
  // let count = 0
  // for (let room in rooms) {
  //   io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
  //     if (err)
  //       cb(err)
  //     allClients.push(clients)
  //     count += clients.length
  //     if (allClients.length === rooms.length) {
  //       cb(null, count)
  //     }
  //   })
  // }
}

getTotalClientsCb(rooms, (err, total) => console.log(total))
```

promises without async / await:

```
function clientsPromise(room) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
      if (err)
        reject(err)
      resolve(clients)
    })
  })
}

function getTotalClientsP(rooms) {
  return rooms.reduce((clientP, room) => 
    clientP.then(count => 
      clientsPromise(room).then(clients => 
        count += clients.length
      )
    )
  , Promise.resolve(0));
  // parallel execution
  // return Promise.all(rooms.map(room => clientsPromise(room))).then(
  //   allClients => allClients.reduce((count, clients) => count += clients.length, 0)
  // )
}

getTotalClientsP(rooms).then(total => console.log(total))
```

with async / await (builds off answer from @Shubham Katri)

```
function getTotalClientsAA(rooms) {
  let count = 0
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    for (let room in rooms) {
      try {
        const clients = await clientsPromise(room);
        count += clients.length
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
    };
    resolve(count)
  })
}

getTotalClientsAA(rooms).then(total => console.log(total))
```

or you could make use of either promise based method inside your function that needs the count by declaring it `async` (though this may cause unintended issues in some frameworks):

```
async function myMainFucntion() {
   const rooms = ['1', '2', '2'];
   const totalClients = await getTotalClientsP(rooms); // or getTotalClientsAA(rooms)
   console.log(totalClients);
}
```

rxjs (external lib but very idiomatic IMO):

```
import { bindNodeCallback, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';

// for parallel
// import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs'
// import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

function clients$(room) {
  return bindNodeCallback(io.in(room).clients)()
}

function getTotalClients$(rooms) {
  return concat(...rooms.map(room => clients$(room))).pipe(
    reduce((count, clients) => count += clients.length, 0)
  )
  // parallel execution
  // return forkJoin(rooms.map(room => clients$(room))).pipe(
  //   map(allClients => allClients.reduce((count, clients) => count += clients.length, 0))
  // )
}

getTotalClients$(rooms).subscribe(total => console.log(total))
```

and a stackblitz to play with these:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xesqn9?file=index.ts

Comment: there's a few errors, like using await in a non-async function

Comment: yea the rxjs bind was broken too. reduced it to the two that worked for now

Comment: just a note this probably won't satisfy what the OP wants, being that he wants a simple loop that will "wait" until the room has a replied value before continuing iteration.

Comment: these are all loops (of sorts) that will not execute the next room fetch until the current is completed... sometimes async / await doesn't play nice with older libraries, i have no idea how well it integrates with socket io or the redis adapter. These are alternatives to achieving sequential async execution that will definitely work

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

let rooms = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3']

rooms.forEach(room => {

    io.in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
      myEmitter.emit('cantUsers', room, clients.length); 
    });

  });

myEmitter.on('cantUsers', (room, cant) => {
  console.log(`In ${room} there are ${cant} users online`);
});
```